# Cannot create custom post types with a specific name

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, 404-error, custom-post-type-archives

I am creating custom post types using this code

```php
function create_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type('courses',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Courses'),
                'singular_name' => __('Course')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
            'taxonomies' => array('category')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_custom_post_type');
```

This code successfully works and shows and the archive pages shows as well but the posts give a 404 error, If i name the custom post types anything else like Lessons then it works
I have done everything like cleared the rewrite rules, saved the permalink settings again after creating a post but it does not work
Can anyone help
Thanks,

Comment: `courses` is quite generic are you sure there isn't already a CPT with the same slug? I also saw you put `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'courses'),` in the code but this seems unnecessary given the CPT already has the name `courses` and is probably causing problems. Have you used a rewrite rules tester plugin to confirm it matches the rules from the CPT and not something 3rd party/something else it shouldn't?

Comment: @TomJNowell i did remove the slug now but it's still not working, can you recommend me some rewrite tester plugins, what i am not understanding is that why are other CPT working but not with this name, i have not created any other CPT as well

Comment: @TomJNowell ok i did test using a tester plugin and i see another rewrite rule for course, could this be conflicting with the name courses?

Comment: yes, WP will go from the highest priority rule and use the first one that matches then ignore the rest, if your rule matches too but has a lower priority it will not be used or even tested

Comment: @TomJNowell so is there no way i can use courses word for custom post type even though the other rewrite rule is named 'course' not 'courses'

Comment: nothing is stopping you from naming your CPT `courses`, that's not the problem, the problem is entirely specific to rewrite rules. Without knowing what or where the `course` rewrite rule comes from though there is no way to answer the question. You'll need to provide more details. If it's because you've registered something named `course` then the answer may be to swap the order you register things in. For rewrite rules order and priority are significant

Comment: @TomJNowell I did not name anything course myself, `course/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$` This is one of the rewrite rule i am seeing for `course`

Comment: are you sure? that rewrite rule came from somewhere, are you sure it's the rewrite rule that's used and not just a matching rule? It looks like a rule from post registration. WP uses the _first_ matching rule starting with the highest priority. Additionally, the 404 error are you sure it's an actual 404 and that your theme distinguishes between empty archives and 404s? Is it a HTTP 404? Can you edit this information including screenshots of the rewrite rule tester you used into your question? Do you have custom taxonomies with the same name?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes i had a plugin which was adding this rewrite rule, That tester plugin helped me see it, Thanks